# what value should we put for Devices attribute while calculating azure stream analytics pricing

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-edge, stream-analytics

I need to calculate pricing for azure stream analytics and i'm confused with the field 'Devices' under 'Stream Analytics on IoT Edge'. is it important for estiamating pricing ? if yes, how to fill it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you planning to run Azure Stream Analytics jobs on edge devices?

Note that this is not running Azure Stream Analytics jobs on edge device **data**. But actually deploying jobs on a device so it can run the query locally.

For most use cases the answer to the first answer is no, and 0 should be put in that box.